# Is the gravitational field of single atom extended around into the space without limits and with the speed of light?

Tags: particle-physics, gravity

Is the gravitational field of single atom extended around into the space without limits and with the speed of light?
It's just very hard to imagine that even single atom creates force around itself that can be detected many millions light years away.
If it's so it would mean that all the existing matter is interconnected like a huge monolithic object. There is no real space(or vacuum). Everything is filled with matter.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Are you asking whether or not the gravitational field of a single atom exists throughout all space, or are you asking whether changes in the gravitational field propagate at the speed of light?

Comment: both. but more the first.

Comment: I am asking a complex question. The atom is just an example of a particle. Any particle propagating gravitational field is ok. As far I know it's now generally accepted that gravitational interaction propagates with the speed of light.

Comment: You are correct in that the gravitational field propagates at the speed of light. Also, yes, the gravitational field does fill all space.

Comment: And it's very cool. Breathtaking.

Comment: "even single atom creates force around itself " Please note that a field is not a force per se. It it is a force *field*. The force appears when a test particle is introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the field equations (Newton's or Einstein's) do give an infinite range. But that doesn't mean the atom is detectable - other matter and noise sources will overwhelm the measurement. But, yes, field theories make the vacuum very different from empty.

Comment: It means there is no such a thing as "emptiness". Everything is filled at least with gravitational field. It's not detectable yet and by us. Only because we don't have yet an efficient way to detect it but reality allows to do it. If one moves even single atom a light year away it can be detected. That atom will propagate the change. Now I have another question: how does the delay caused by the speed of light affect that all?

Comment: @ivanavdeyev the speed $c$ (I avoid "speed of light" here because it is also the speed of other things, here gravity) allows causality. It also allows triangulation of the location of various events by sensor arrays with synchronized clocks. Did you have a particular effect you were wondering about?

Comment: Thanks for the generalization "c". No I didn't. I just was amazed by the fact that all the existing matter is connected (at least in the area limited by the speed c). Now I started to think about what happens outside that area and how such areas interact each other.